# how to call javascript function from android using phonegap plugin 

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova, call

This is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>PhoneGap</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.7.0rc1.js"></script>      
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    function call(){
      console.log("ANDROID");
    }
    </script>

</head>
<body >
</body>
</html>
```

This is my receiver class

```
package com.example.jsfrmjv;
import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class BootReciver extends BroadcastReceiver {
Context ctx;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("BBBBOOOOOOOOOOTTTTTTT COMPLETED");
    Log.d("ALARM STRIKE", "Reboot completed");

    //Pluginjava pl = new Pluginjava();
        //((DroidGap) this.ctx).sendJavascript("javascript:call()");                
}   
}
```

So, Whenever i restart my phone , this receiver should call the call() method in javascript in index.html. Using Phonegap plugin , i m able to call the java method from index.html.But in this case , i need to call a method in javascript from this receiver class. Thank you for your future help. Please help to resolve this issue.This is urgent guys.

Answer (score 3):

There are more then one way to do so, to call the java script function from `MainActivity` is

```
this.sendJavascript("appResumed");
```

Here appResumed is javascript function name.

Comment: Hey @Rajnikant, can you tell me in which JS this `appResumed` function should be. In `index.js` or in the `plugin JS` file. Because I am not able to call a JS method using the `sendJavascript()`, but when I write a statement like `sendJavascript("alert(Hello')")`. So, please tell me how to achieve this. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

you will get the right answer [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/1o9PgfmyRd8)

Comment: This function is not leveraging phonegap capability.